# weird shading problem

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

i'm completely lost. i'm a beginner 3d modeler, and i can't figure what's exactly wrong with my model. the topology is far from perfect, but also not awful, so i'm confused why shading looks so bad
i already tried recalculating normals, checking for additional faces/verticles, enabling autosmooth. maybe i missed something or i should just remake the model? [image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: yes, here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/2JMOJbMr/

Comment: These artefact seem to be caused by the sun orientation, also its Strength is very high, lower it down to a more reasonable value like 4 or 5, maybe also increase its Angle?

Comment: oh my god, i can't believe that was the problem.... i didn't even noticed that the strenght was so high. thank you so much!!

Comment: @bjaodk Well, the default _Point_ light in the default scene has a _Strength_ of 1000 W. If you change it from _Point_ to _Sun_, the strength value of 1000 stays, only now this is 1000 W/m² which is much much more ;) Although this value is actually accurate to a bright sunny day, the Blender camera's exposure is not adapted to that since you cannot set an aperture like on a real camera - the _Aperture_ which you can change in the camera properties _Depth of Field_ is only used for defocusing effects, not exposure changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These artefacts seem to be caused by the sun orientation, rotate it a bit on Z, also its *Strength* is very high, lower it down to a more reasonable value like 4 or 5, maybe also increase its *Angle* to make the shadow smoother.